# Does "all the way along" mean "all the way until the end"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

This is from a native speaker who teaches a practical way for removing mold over the silicone sealants in bathrooms. [how to remove mold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRM-IsGzLug) (see 1:11-1:12) He says:

**"I'm going to do the same all the way along".**

If I understand correctly, he, by saying **".....all the way along"**, means laying the paper towel over the mold in the form of a thin line. But I am not quite sure about whether he simply means this or the word **"along"** gives also a meaning **"..... until the point where the mold ends."**

So, as a non-native speaker I am not quite sure whether **"along"** gives a meaning of **"in the form of a line"** or  **"in the form of a line until the very end".**

So, does it mean;

1-**"I'm going to do the same all the way in the form of a line".**

2- **"I'm going to do the same all the way in the form of a line until the end of the line".**

Comment: I don't know how to explain the different contexts, but unquestionably it's always ***all the way along*** in OP's exact context, but *The footpath from my house to the pub is litter-strewn **all along the way*** is a perfectly valid sequence. Maybe it's something to do with *distance traveled*.

Answer (score 2):

It means both "following the line, without leaving any gaps" and (arguably included in the above) "reaching to the end".

The first semantic element is "along", which here means "parallel to or matching a linear path".

The second is "all the way", which here means "not missing any part" and "reaching the end". Without "all the way", one could lay paper towel "along" a path even if one left gaps at regular intervals. (Compare "towns along a river" or "stations along the railway line".)